# PHP Chaining setter magic method

Tags: php, set, magic-methods

Hi in my php application i would like to use class like this `$Class->Var1->Var2 = 'Value'`, and inside class i would have array that should then contain following

```
    Array
    (
      [Var1] => Array
        (
            [Var2] => Value
        )

    )
```

Can this be achieved with chaining __set method ?

Comment: do you need arrays? `$foo = new StdClass(); $foo->var1->var2 = 'bar';` works just fine as-is.

Comment: @MarcB: `Creating default object from empty value`.  This works: `$foo = new StdClass(); $foo->var1['var2'] = 'bar';`

Comment: well yeah, thnaks for that i dont know how i did overlooked that